# Shopify: how do I get the Product Name to the Input Field form when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have this function works well with me to get the URL of page using Input Field:

```
var url      = window.location.href;
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#url').val(url);
});
```

I want to make it works to get Product Name, please can anyone show me how I can do that? note that I want to use it with Shopify Store.

Here's the input field code:

```
<input type="text" name="entry.123456789" id="url" value="" style="display: none;">
```

Thanks y'all guys in advance for your help!

Comment: This comment just to rank the question again, please anyone ca help!

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has a global product object available on Product pages. If you need this form on some product page, then using the code below should work fine.

```
<input type="text" name="product-title" value="{{product.title}}" style="display: none;">
```

If you need it on some other page, get a single product object (e.g using all_products) and then use the title property.

Moreover, from the display none, I have understood that you just need to get this data when form is submitted and does not need input from user. In that case, hidden field is recommended.

```
<input type="hidden" name="product-title" value="{{product.title}}">
```

As per addition in comments, if you are trying to get this on Cart page, the available object is named as **[cart](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/files/cart-liquid)**. You can loop over the products in cart and then get title.

```
{% for line_item in cart.items %}
    <input type="hidden" name="product-title-{{line_item.product_id}}" value="{{line_item.product.title}}">

    {{line_item.product.title}} - {{line_item.quantity}}

{% endfor %}
```

This will generate the hidden input fields. Change the input name accordingly.

[Input Type Hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

[Shopify Product Object](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/product#product-title)

Comment: Hi @Bilal Akbar, thanks for your response. I tried the code you gave me but didn't work! to be in the image, I use Google Responses entries (Example: name="entry.1928282") +Google Spreadsheets, and I want to use the code in the Cart Page ( https://www.example.com/cart ), now I want to collect some information then I will contact the buyer to complete his purchase but I want to know which products he added to Cart, hope you understand what I want to do and if you have any trick to collect products name that added to Cart. Thank you so much

Comment: I tried with this code:
`<input type="hidden" name="entry.1005501188" id="pdata" value="{{ item.product.title }}" style="display: none;">`

Comment: But if I use this `name="product-title-{{line_item.product_id}}"`, how I can add `name="entry.1005501188"` because I don't know how to duplicate it! As I mentioned before I use Google Responses Entries with Spreadsheets to collects those information

Comment: thank you so much it works just by adding ID `{% for line_item in cart.items %}
    <input type="hidden" name="product-title-{{line_item.product_id}}" id="pdata" value="{{line_item.product.title}}">
{% endfor %}`
, now I still have a problem if the customer added more more than 1 product on cart, how we can collects each product name with quantity like this **Product Name1 (Qty), Product Name2 (Qty)**. Thank you so much for your time and help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Hi @Bilal Akbar, it's working but not giving me multiple products on the spreadsheet!

`{% for line_item in cart.items %}
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.1005501162" id="pdata" value="">
    <span class="ppdata">{{line_item.product.title}}, {{line_item.quantity}} -<span>
{% endfor %}`

, I think we can use Javascript to collect data in value based on Class like in the URL field? do you know how we can do that? because the data are collected correctly even if we have more products was added to the page, it appears because we didn't hide them using CSS. Or do you have any other trick

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I don't know how Google Responses Entries work. My answer above only refers to Shopify.

Comment: Ah I see bro, btw thank you so much for your answer, because it helps me to solve a 90% of this issue, Thanks again for your time and help my friend Bilal